# VB.net Tile Graphics Drawing - Isometric

Tags: vb.net

I am working on just a small game in Vb.net (I know this is not a great place to make a game but I'm just doing a little project). I have a project set up where I am trying to make an isometric tile map. To make it easier on myself, I wanted to get all the locations set first, so I took picture boxes and found the exact locations for where I want to draw each tile. Now what I would like to do is draw an image at each location and I'm not sure how to go about this.

(something like, for each picturebox.location draw graphics.tile1????)

thank you!

Comment: Why not display the images in the picture boxes instead of drawing them on the form.

Comment: wont that be a big performance hit though?

Comment: No it won't . Can you post a screenshot of what you are trying to do?